# How can I find the exact part number of a 2008 highlander strut?

Tags: struts, replacements, highlander

I want to change the front passenger side strut of a Toyota highlander 2008 sport AWD with 130K. But I don't know what is the exact product I must buy? (Either OEM or after market).

I also like to know if is it a good idea to find a salvaged highlander with the same and healthy strut? If so, what models have same strut as 2008 sport AWD model?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

It appears from what I'm seeing, on the front end of the Highlander, the struts are the same between the AWD and FWD models. This makes sense, since both models have driven wheels up front. It's the rear struts which are different between the two.

As for the crossover, my research shows 2008-2010 are compatible. So you'd be able to find them on either the AWD or FWD versions of those years.

The easiest way I've been able to find parts for any vehicle is to go to RockAuto.com and see what is on there. They have a very large inventory of different parts for most vehicles domestic to the States. (NOTE: I have no affiliation with RockAuto.com, nor do I endorse their products or online site.) I use RockAuto.com because they are awesome for their parts numbers and cross referencing between models. Tons of information.

Anyways, there are several parts numbers which are available from separate manufacturers for the front right strut:

```
Manufacturer                     Part No.
MONROE                           72483
KYB                              339230
GABRIEL                          G52201
FCS                              33319R
PRT                              474283
API                              2701423335
```

Two things of note:

1. You can go to a wrecking yard and get a strut. Unless you're desperate, I wouldn't. Go get new ones. If you happened to find them in a wrecking yard and could verify the mileage on them as being low, that's the only way I'd purchase them and place them on my vehicle. Otherwise, what you're getting is most likely worn out anyways.
2. That's right, I said "new **ones**". Again, only if you are desperate and strapped for money would you only replace one. Replace both of them on the same axle at the same time. If one is bad, the other isn't far behind. The only time I might not replace both of them is if there was very low mileage on them.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know among the brands you mentioned for buying a new one, which brand is better? Also what is the brand of original ones that Toyota used on this cars? Are the original ones better than other brands?

Comment: @GoodMan - shopping recommendations are not on topic here, for various reasons. You could look at what brands are available where you are, and look on rating sites to see which is best.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: What about the OEM parts? Can I know which strut is exactly what brand Toyota uses when it manufactures it's products? Please give me the exact product brand/number that Toyota uses/used to check it's price.

Comment: I have no idea what it would be, @GoodMan. You could probably ask a Toyota dealer, or search on Toyota spares sites.

Comment: @GoodMan - Realistically, it really doesn't matter which one is the OEM ones used. Of the six I mentioned, Monroe, KYB, & Gabriel all make good replacement struts. I'm sure the other three are not far behind, but as Rory states, you need to do your homework and read the reviews for those parts, then make your own decision.

Comment: I found that there are regular and sport tuned suspensions in highlander sport models. How can I find if mine is regular or sport tuned?

Comment: @GoodMan - Take your VIN to the dealership. They should be able to print you out all the options it came with from the factory.